# Issue with a return value in Python

Tags: python, return

So I have a very specific issue:

```
def check_balance():
    """Check the current user's balance"""

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    balance = cursor.execute('SELECT balance FROM card WHERE number = :number',
                             {'number': self.card_number}).fetchone()[0]
    cursor.close()
    return balance

def close_account():
    """Close account i.e. delete it from the database"""

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('DELETE FROM card WHERE number = :number', {'number': self.card_number})
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    raise LogOut('The account has been closed!')

try:
    menu_dict = {1: check_balance, 2: add_income, 3: do_transfer, 4: close_account, 5: log_out, 0: exit}
    option = int(input())
    menu_dict.get(option)()
except LogOut as logout:
    print(logout)`
```

So, here I have this dispatcher that just calls some functions depending on the input value. And the problem is that, for example, `check_balance` function returns the balance as an integer, right, and I'd like to print the result as 'Balance: "return value"'. I can't change return value of this function to string as it's used mostly as an integer in many places. I wonder if it's possible to implement it in pretty way somehow. Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with an example of printing `Balance: "return value"`

Comment: @quamrana hah, that's the main issue here, I don't know how to implement it that way so it would print 'Balance: "and here goes result of the check_balance func"'. I stated everything needed to solve it. Return type is integer, I said it in the question as well

Comment: You have the burden of showing some code which doesn't work. What you have so far is code that works. When you can show something which doesn't work, we can begin to understand what you are getting at.

Comment: @quamrana I think you're not understanding the main point of my issue. Code works anyway. I don't need help in making it work, I'm asking for help with printing the output the way I described in the question, how can output of a function that just returns an integer help you? Furthermore, I can't even do it, because, as I said, that's what I need help with, print it in that pattern: 'Balance: "return value"'. I hope it's clear now

Comment: Not at all. I suggest to you that your existing functions (`check_balance`, `add_income` etc)  are just fine. If you need to print something out, then it is up to you to demonstrate *something*. You even have a fine answer from @I4sh which *does* include some `print()` statements.

Comment: You see, functions like `check_balance` return a value, but many others don't, so if I `print(menu_dict.get(option)()` in most of the cases it will return None. That's why I tried to know if there is a way to avoid that neatly or it's only possible by making the following
`result = menu_dict.get(option)();
if result: print(result)`

Comment: Thanks to this new information, I now see where you have a problem. Please update your question with this code which doesn't work along with the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to change what you are calling:

```py
def check_balance():
    return 42
def close_account():
    print('account closed')
    
menu_dict = {1: lambda: print(check_balance()), 4: close_account}
option = int(input('Select 1 or 4: '))
menu_dict.get(option)()
```

Here I use a `lambda` to only print the return value from `check_balance()`

Comment: Really appreciate your help, this solution is just what I was looking for. It's nice and neat. Thank you a lot. You made an important contribution in my skillset. Doubt a lot about that I would be able to find something so specific somewhere else. Have a good one and thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Assuming

```
...
value = menu_dict.get(option)()
```

Depending on the Python version you're using you can use any of the following.

f-strings

```
print(f"Balance: {value}")
```

str.format()

```
print("Balance: {}".format(value))
```

Old style formatting

```
print('Balance: %i' % value)
```

Or plain old casting and concatenating strings

```
print("Balance: " + str(value))
```

More info:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: that's exactly the solution I came up with as a temporary one that just does its job, I'm trying to get any information if it's possible to implement it in another way without strings attached, maybe changing something in the function itself